# SQL Find student names according to grade

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to print student names for each student that has more than one "2" grade. Grade is integer from `CLASSSTUDENT` table. Oracle database.
Code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
FROM PERSON  
JOIN STUDENT ON PERSON.PERSONID = STUDENT.STUDENTID 
JOIN CLASSSTUDENT ON STUDENT.STUDENTID = CLASSSTUDENT.STUDENTID
WHERE FINALGRADE = 2;
```

This get students having grade of "2". How must I change query to get students with more than one "2" grade?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `HAVING`.

Comment: I have tried adding GROUP BY FIRSTNAME
HAVING COUNT (CLASSSTUDENT.FINALGRADE) > 1; but I am wrong somewhere

Comment: Can you post the table structure for `PERSON`, `STUDENT`, and `CLASSSTUDENT` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Student s ON p.PersonID = s.StudentID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT StudentID
    FROM ClassStudent
    WHERE FinalGrade = 2
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) f ON f.StudentID = s.StudentID
```

or more simply:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN ClassStudent cs ON cs.StudentID = p.PersonID
WHERE cs.FinalGrade = 2
GROUP BY cs.StudentID, FirstName, LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Though I prefer the former for reasons I don't myself fully understand (possibly something to do with only grouping on the primary key, or only using the group to filter the records... but really it just "feels" more right somehow).

Comment: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: Had WHERE/GROUP BY out of order. Try it again

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be something like:

```
 SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, COUNT(*)
 FROM PERSON  
 JOIN STUDENT ON PERSON.PERSONID = STUDENT.STUDENTID 
 JOIN CLASSSTUDENT ON STUDENT.STUDENTID = CLASSSTUDENT.STUDENTID
 WHERE FINALGRADE = 2
 GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```